# Evaluate $\int^ {\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\cos (x)}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$ via contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I know the solution to be $\frac{\pi}{2e}$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{-iz}}{(z^2+1)^2}$ on the classic upper semicircle contour ( note that the integrand is even). $f$ has a double pole at $z=i$ inside this contour with residue $0$. It is clear that $f$ vanishes on the semi-circle as we take the radius to infinity. Hence by the residue theorem I should get, upon taking real parts, $\int^ {\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\cos (x)}{(x^2+1)^2}=0 \neq \frac{\pi}{2e}$. What's wrong with my argument? Many thanks.

Comment: In your path, the pole at $z=i$ is enclosed and this gives you a residue.

Comment: I think I stated this in my attempt. However I got residue $0$ for this pole, which I checked with matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\cos(z)=\operatorname{Re}(e^{iz})$. So, it is natural to consider the integral of $\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+1)^2}$, whose residue at $i$ is $-\frac i{2e}$. Therefore$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos x}{(x^2+1)^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac\pi e.$$

Comment: Which contour are you considering? If you use my contour, which I think you are, this choice of $f$ is sure to blow up on the upper semi circle?! Surely you would have to consider the lower semicircle and then you would run into the same issue as before?! Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am using your contour. So, I am only dealing with $z$'s such that $\operatorname{Im}z\geqslant0$, and therefore $\lvert e^{iz}\rvert=e^{\operatorname{Re}(iz)}=e^{-\operatorname{Im}z}\leqslant1$.

Comment: I see so you approach definitely works then! Thanks. Where does my approach fail? Do I get blowup?

Comment: I think my function blows up on the imaginary line! So I see where I went wrong! Many thanks.